# How to limit count of checked checkboxes equal to select value using jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, radio-button, html-select

I'm trying to limit the amount of checkboxes able to be checked according to what select option the user chooses i.e. `option1 = 1` checkbox `option 2 = 2` checkboxes and if they try to choose more then alert the user and `.prop("checked", false)`.

but i just get weird stuff happening and i can't figure why please help!!

html:

```
<form>
    <select onclick="systemSelected();" class="mySelectBox">
        <option value="1">option1</option>
        <option value="2">option2</option>
        <option value="3">option3</option>
        <option value="4">option4</option>
        <option value="5">option5</option>
    </select>
</form>
<form onclick="limitCheckbox(userSelected);">
    <input type="checkbox" name="box1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="box2">
    <input type="checkbox" name="box3">
    <input type="checkbox" name="box4">
    <input type="checkbox" name="box5">
</form>
```

javascript:

```
var userSelected = 0;
function systemSelected() {
    $(".mySelectBox option").each(function(){
        if ($(this.selected)) {
            userSelected = parseInt($(".mySelectBox").val());
        }
    });
}
function limitCheckbox(userSystem) {
    $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function(){
        if($("input[type=checkbox]:checked".length > userSystem)) {
            $(this).prop("checked", false);
            alert("too many numbers");
        } else if ($("input[type=checkbox]:checked".length === 0 )) {    
            alert("please select a game too play");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Do you absolutely *have* to use two independent `<form>` elements for this, or is that for presentation? (This is entirely tangential to your question however.)

Answer (score 2):

1. **Don't use alerts** (Why should a user feel stupid)
2. **Use the `disabled` property** (Make a user see & know)

```js
var $ckb = $('[name*=box]'),
    $sel = $('.mySelectBox');

function ckkk () {

  var ckd = $ckb.filter(":checked").length,
      max = parseInt($sel.val(), 10);

  if(ckd > max) $ckb.prop({checked:false, disabled:false});
  else        $ckb.not(":checked").prop({disabled: ckd >= max});


}

$ckb.add($sel).on("change", ckkk);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="mySelectBox">
  <option value="1">option1</option>
  <option value="2">option2</option>
  <option value="3">option3</option>
  <option value="4">option4</option>
  <option value="5">option5</option>
</select>

<input type="checkbox" name="box1">
<input type="checkbox" name="box2">
<input type="checkbox" name="box3">
<input type="checkbox" name="box4">
<input type="checkbox" name="box5">
```

Comment: disabled is a good idea, I'm still learning a lot of things thanks to all that answered!

Answer (score 0):

use `$("input[type=checkbox]").on('change',function(){` selector which will fire event on every change of checkbox. And you can manage your cases with conditions in it.

Please check below snippet.

```js
var userSelected = 0;
  $("input[type=checkbox]").on('change',function(){
    if($("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length > parseInt($(".mySelectBox").val())) {
      $(this).prop("checked", false);
      alert("too many numbers");


    } else if ($("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length === 0 ) {

      alert("please select a game too play");
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select class="mySelectBox">
    <option value="1">option1</option>
    <option value="2">option2</option>
    <option value="3">option3</option>
    <option value="4">option4</option>
    <option value="5">option5</option>
  </select>

</form>

<form>
  <input type="checkbox" name="box1">
  <input type="checkbox" name="box2">
  <input type="checkbox" name="box3">
  <input type="checkbox" name="box4">
  <input type="checkbox" name="box5">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('input:checkbox').change(function() {

  var number = $('.mySelectBox option:selected').val();

  if ($('input:checkbox:checked').length > number) {


    alert('more than selected')
    $(this).prop('checked', false);//dont check the click checkbox
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select class="mySelectBox">
    <option value="1">option1</option>
    <option value="2">option2</option>
    <option value="3">option3</option>
    <option value="4">option4</option>
    <option value="5">option5</option>
  </select>

</form>

<form>
  <input type="checkbox" name="box1">
  <input type="checkbox" name="box2">
  <input type="checkbox" name="box3">
  <input type="checkbox" name="box4">
  <input type="checkbox" name="box5">
</form>
```